# How to receive response from an API endpoint to bind the DataTablein Blazor server project

Tags: asp.net-core, .net-core, datatables, asp.net-core-webapi, blazor-server-side

Below is the `code` I'm using to bind `DataTable`. This same code works fine with an `MVC` project with `MVC controller`. But facing problems when trying the same code with `API controller.`

```
 `window.UpcomingPaymentTables = {
   dataTable: null,

buildDataTable: function () {
    this.dataTable = $("#UpcomingPaymentsGrid").DataTable({
        columnDefs: [
            { targets: [0], data: "Date" },
            { targets: [1], data: "Amount" }
        ],
        processing: true,
        stateSave: true,
        serverSide: true,
        filter: true,
        lengthMenu: [[10, 25, 50], [10, 25, 50]],
        autoWidth: false,
        ajax: {
            url: "/api/Plans/GetUpcomingPayments",
            type: 'POST',
            dataFilter: function (resp) {
                debugger;
                return resp;
            },
            error: function (xhr, error, code) {
                alert(error);
            }
        }
    });
},
destroyDataTable: function () {
    if (this.dataTable) {
        this.dataTable.destroy();
    }
}
  }`
```

Receiving an empty `object` in "resp" variable of dataFilter.

Below is the `API` endpoint:

```
    [HttpPost]
    [Route("GetUpcomingPayments")]
    public DataTablesResult GetUpcomingPayments([FromForm] DataTablesRequest request)
    {
        var data = _planService.GetUpcomingPayments(122).ReadDataTable(request);
        
        DataTablesResult rs = new DataTablesResult(data);
        return rs;
    }
```

`DataTablesResult` has all the required `properties` for `Datatable`. The same code is working for the `MVC controller`. the only difference is I'm trying it with `API Controller`.
In `API Controller` I had to pass the DataTablesRequest object using [FromForm] while in `MVC controller` it doesn't need.

Using the following `code` on a `razor component` to call the `js` functions.

```
protected override async Task OnAfterRenderAsync(bool firstRender)
    {
        if (firstRender)
        {
            await _jsRuntime.InvokeVoidAsync("UpcomingPaymentTables.destroyDataTable");
            await _jsRuntime.InvokeVoidAsync("UpcomingPaymentTables.buildDataTable");
        }       

    }
```

Am I missing something in `API controller` to return the data in the required format?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**Update:**

Do not define `$upcomingTable` and `udt`, use them directly, because you are calling `window.UpcomingPaymentTables`, the definition is not recognized externally:

```
window.UpcomingPaymentTables = {
    buildDataTable: function () {
        this.dataTable = $("#UpcomingPaymentsGrid").DataTable({
            //...
        });
    },
    destroyDataTable: function () {
        if (this.dataTable) {
            this.dataTable.destroy();
        }
    }
}
```

---

The corresponding data is not passed in your `ajax` request, which will cause the Api call to fail. In the JSON returned from the Api, the keys are all lowercase by default. Also, I'm not sure how the `rs` you return look like, but make sure it's of type `List/Array/Enumerable`.

Below is a working demo, you can refer to it (For convenience, I just used the `DataTablesRequest` model).

DataTablesRequest:

```
public class DataTablesRequest
{ 
    public string Date { get; set; }
    public string Amount { get; set; }
}
```

TestController:

```
[Route("api/[controller]")]
[ApiController]
public class TestController : ControllerBase
{
    [HttpPost]
    [Route("GetUpcomingPayments")]
    public List<DataTablesRequest> Get([FromForm] DataTablesRequest request)
    {
        var Request = new DataTablesRequest() 
        {
            Date = "Date1",
            Amount = "Amount1"
        };

        var RequestList = new List<DataTablesRequest>() { Request };
        return RequestList;

    }
}
```

DataTables.razor:

```
@page "/datatables"
@implements IDisposable
@using BlazorApp.Shared
@inject HttpClient Http
@inject IJSRuntime JS

<table class="table" id="dt2">
    <thead>
        <tr>
            <th>Date</th>
            <th>Amount</th>
        </tr>
    </thead>
</table>

@code {
    protected override async Task OnAfterRenderAsync(bool firstRender)
    {
        await base.OnAfterRenderAsync(firstRender);

        if (firstRender)
        {
            await JS.InvokeVoidAsync("DataTables.buildDataTable");
        }
    }

    async void IDisposable.Dispose()
    {
        await JS.InvokeVoidAsync("DataTables.destroyDataTable");
    }
}
```

DataTables.js:

```
window.DataTables = {
    dataTable: null,
    buildDataTable: function (ajaxUrl) {
        var data = {
            "Date": "TestDate",
            "Amount": "TestAmount"
        }
        this.dataTable = $("#dt2").DataTable({
            "ajax": {
                "url": "/api/Test/GetUpcomingPayments",
                "type": "POST",
                "data": data,
                "dataSrc": "",
                "dataFilter": function (resp) {
                    debugger;
                    return resp;
                },
                "error": function (xhr, error, code) {
                    alert(error);
                }
            },
            columnDefs: [
                //lowercase
                { targets: [0], data: "date" },
                { targets: [1], data: "amount" }
            ],
            processing: true,
            stateSave: true,
            filter: true,
            lengthMenu: [[10, 25, 50], [10, 25, 50]],
            autoWidth: false
        });
    },
    destroyDataTable: function () {
        if (this.dataTable) {
            this.dataTable.destroy();
        }
    }
}
```

Don't forget to reference the JS file:

```
<script src="js/DataTables.js"></script>
```

Test Result:

[image]

[image]

[image]

Comment: I'm using the quite same process but not sure why Datatable is not binding. It's not throwing any errors as well. Please check my code in this screenshot. https://app.screencast.com/EXMHO39yOxFEF

Comment: Also, facing this error https://app.screencast.com/x6VccnI2jKV4z

Comment: Hi @Code Rider, Please edit as per my updated answer first.